# Nested Table Row Append With Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append, html-table

I am trying to Row Append With Jquery. But New Row Not Generate New Row.
Here is a little example that I setup this table is a nested table.

```
<table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="addTag">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id="lblTagID" />
                    <input type="text" id="txtTagName1" class="form-control" name="field_name[]" />
                </td>
                <td>                                                
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="btnRemoveTag_Click()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete
                </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

And Jquery like this call on one Button

```
function btnAdd_Click() {

    $("#addTag").append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="lblTagID" /><input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_name[]"></td><td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="btnRemoveTag_Click()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</td></tr>');
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where is btnAdd_Click() function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your function on $(document).ready(function(){});
try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah</td></tr>');
    });
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```